# How to take a input in Java from console if we don't know how many lines does each test case have?

Tags: java

I'm recently faced a problem in which I have to take the inputs as a string from user using console. But here is the trick, that is I don't know how many lines of input is. How to take that input ?

This question is based on input/output. In the question there is nothing mentioned that read n lines from the test case. So here I have to read the n lines from the test case from the console without knowing the value of n.

This problem was asked in a coding contest. They have to check the solutions against the many test cases.

For example => Input is =>

```
Hello!
How are you.
I am fine.
That's good.
```

Here I 've to stop taking input at last line "That's good.".

I cannot enter any special char or string to indicate the input system to stop taking any further input because test cases can contain any char or string.

I've tried this one

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

while(true){
    String str=br.readLine();
    if(str.length==0)
        break;
}
```

But in above solution, I've to press enter button twice, one for to change the line and second for to enter nothing so that its length become 0 and loop will break. This is not worked as no test case is passed.

Each test case contains n lines. So is there any trick to see that is there anything in the buffer advance to taking an input.

Comment: "But here is the trick, that is I don't know how many lines of input is. How to take that input ?" I don't understand why you expect this to be a problem. What happened when you tried to write the code?

Comment: You'll just need some way for the user to indicate they've finished giving their input.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel this is the problem I've faced in one of the coding contest. At that time I'm unable to solve it. So I'm trying it now.

Comment: @khelwood But I cannot have the privilege to indicate the user here.

Comment: We can only help you with problems that are actually stated to us. You need to show the question's specifications. Probably it will say something like "the first line of input specifies the number of lines" or something like that, or else it will expect you to read until the end of input, or something else. But we can't tell you how to do something unless we know what is being asked.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I've updated the question for better clarity. Please take a look.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem, including your test cases. You should also explain how these tests are executed. Are you in control of them?

Comment: @Slaw I' already provide the input example in the question.

Comment: Still not a [mre] though. You should provide the actual code for your test cases. Show exactly how they're failing. And you say the input is not in your control. In what way? Who is providing the input? Who is writing the test cases?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to know how many lines the user is going to enter if you are going to store them in a *fixed sized* data structure; e.g. an array.

Solution<sup>1</sup>:  Use a data structure with a dynamic size instead.  Without knowing the details of your application ... an `ArrayList` would probably be a good choice.

---

If your problem is that you can't figure out when to *stop* reading lines from the user, then what you need to do is provide the user with a way to say "I have finished".  It could be:

- A special word; e.g. "done"
- An empty line
- The end of input ... assuming that the user knows how to do that.  (It is typically a `CTRL-D` on Linux / UNIX / MacOS X and `CTRL-Z` on Windows.)

---

> But in above solution, I've to press enter button twice, one for to change the line and second for to enter nothing so that its length become 0 and loop will break.

Well ... yes.  That is how the user enters a *empty* line.  The first `ENTER` is ending the previous (non-empty) line, and the second one is ending the empty line.

It sounds like your program is working as designed.

---

> No your answer doesn't covers it. Because according to your answer I've to type something special to indicate end of input. But input is not in my control. They are test cases, in which anything can be entered.

In that case, you need to run your program differently.

If there are test cases they are not being entered on the keyboard.  Because that is not how automated testcases work. The test cases are most likely to doing this:

```
  $ java YourClass << EOF
  Hello!
  How are you.
  I am fine.
  That's good.
  EOF
```

Or

```
 $ java YourClass < file.txt
```

where `file.txt` contains the above input (part from the `EOF` file).

And the user would do that interactively as follows:

```
 $ java YourClass < file.txt
 Hello!
 How are you.
 I am fine.
 That's good.
 ^D
```

And the way that your program would handle that is to read until the end of the input stream.  That will be signaled by `readLine()` returning `null`.

Before you say that I am wrong, consider this:

Question: If the user doesn't type *something* to say "this is the end", how can your program possibly tell the difference between the user ending the input and the user sitting and scratching his head for a few minutes before typing some more?

Answer: It is not possible to tell ... which is why the user has to type something something.

---

<sup>1 - There are other more complicated solutions that entail allocating a new array and copying, but ... why bother?</sup>

Comment: even if I can use some dynamic data structure then also, I've to take input. And now the question remains the same that how to take an input of n lines without knowing the value of n ?

Comment: Here's the thing.  The original version of your question was terribly unclear.  I have already addressed the updates you have made to the question.  Read my answer again.   (And pay attention to Karl's comment on the question.  We can only answer based on the information that >you write< in your question.  We cannot read your mind.)

Comment: I've updated the question for better clarity. Please take a look.

Comment: I think my answer already covers it.

Comment: no your answer doesn't covers it. Because according to your answer I've to type something special to indicate end of input. But input is not in my control. They are test cases, in which anything can be entered.